# "[..] to bother you again" vs "[..] for bothering you"

Tags: gerunds

What is the difference between

- I am sorry **to bother** you **again**.

and

- I am sorry **for bothering** you.

Do they mean the same thing because ***again*** implies that it is not the first time the person  has bothered the other one; as if "bothering" was an ongoing action (began in the past and  has continued up to now).

So what is the difference? Does the gerund imply that the action has lasted for a long time: a kind of habit?

Comment: Why have you included the word ***again*** in the second ("continuous") example, but not in the first ("infinitive")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence or absence of "again" is totally unrelated to the difference between "sorry **for** + *gerund*" and "sorry **to** + *infinitive*." All four of the following are possible and perfectly natural:

- Sorry **for** bothering you.
- Sorry **for** bothering you **again**.
- Sorry **to** bother you.
- Sorry **to** bother you **again**.

"Again" is simple: you can include this if you have previously "bothered" this person and are apologizing for a second or subsequent occurrence.

The difference between "sorry **for**" and "sorry **to**" is more subtle. "Sorry for bothering you" works when you have already bothered the person -- not necessarily a second occurrence, but the bothering has already begun, so to speak. It would fit at the end of the conversation. The thing you are apologizing for is a concrete thing that has already happened or at least started to happen.

"Sorry to bother you" works better at the beginning of the conversation: the thing you are apologizing for is a detached, almost hypothetical thing, as if it hasn't occurred yet or is only just starting to occur.

The distinction between the two is a little blurry, and if you said "sorry to bother you" at the *end* of the conversation -- or "sorry for bothering you" at the beginning -- it's unlikely anyone would even notice, let alone care that you used the "wrong" form. So don't worry about this too much, but here's a simple scenario to help it stick in your mind.

> - Sorry **to** bother you -- could I borrow your pencil?
> - Sure. Here.
> - Thanks. Sorry **for** bothering you.

> - Sorry **to** bother you **again** -- could I borrow your eraser?
> - Sure. Here.
> - Thanks. Sorry **for** bothering you **again**.

Comment: Can I use sorry for bothering at the beginning of a conversation if it  began in the past and has continued up to now

Comment: @YvesLefol Do you mean a situation where you've been doing something that's been bothering this person (say, listening to loud music) and have just started to talk about it? Then, sure, you could say "sorry for bothering you." (Don't leave off the pronoun.)